# Fixing dynamic responsive navigation when there are more items than the container has width

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, navigation

So I'm currently working with some dynamic navigation. Just the basic HTML markup of a <ul><li> composition. My problem occurs when the user added too many items into this navigation and there isn't enough room for them within its container (imagine this is a simple <div>).

So, I need a solution. I was wondering if there would be a way to determine when the width of the <ul> is larger than or equal to the containing <div>'s width, then it would inject the remaining <li> elements into a new <li> which would basically be a dropdown for them all. Would this be possible and if so how?

I know the basics of jQuery but I'm afraid I'm not too sure on this. Oh and, it will need to work responsively so it would need to work with percentages too.

Let me know if this is feasible or if you have a better way around this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I have updated the github repo with the plan I outlined.

--

I would use jQuery for this. The idea I'm having is as follows.

You would get the <div>'s width, then add up all the widths of the <li>'s and see if they are bigger.
Then take off as many as needed so the <li>'s fit into the <div>.

Then add all the ones you took off into a new <li> with another <ul> for a dropdown.

I'm happy to write something for this, but wont be till later when I finish work.

I have a responsive nav on my github, its doesn't to exactly what your after, but this sounds like a really good update, so once i've written something i'll add it to my github version.
https://github.com/MartinBlackburn/responsive-nav